# How to change brace indentation style in Emacs/ AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I would like to use something like the Allman or BSD style for LaTeX. For example, I would indent the following code like this:

```
\iflanguage{english}{
    \begin{otherlanguage}{brazilian}
}{
    \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
}
```

But AUCTeX indents it like this:

```
\iflanguage{english}{
  \begin{otherlanguage}{brazilian}
    }{
      \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
        }
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542040/how-to-change-brace-indentation-levels-in-emacs) is similar, but the solution does not work since LaTeX is not C-like.

[This page](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/restricted-resources/utma-doc/emacs/auctex/auc-tex.html) describes the variable `'TeX-brace-indent-level'`, but it controls only `{`. Does the same exist for `}`?

Comment: I'm surprised AUCTeX wpould indent it this way.  FWIW, the built-in latex-mode indents pretty much just like you want.

Comment: @Stefan I just realized that the problem is with the '\begin' inside: the '{' are indented as if they were part of '\begin{otherlanguage}'.